# In Logback using custom AppenderBase class and howto send notifications back to Swing gui

Tags: java, listener, logback

The class example below `MyAppender` is called from the logback.xml file.

When the `append()` is called by logback i have no reference to the
class `MyAppender`so i cannot attach any `Observer` or register a `Listener`

Does logback have some Listener the Swing gui can register or what should i do?

Have been reading the [logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/joran.html) but i cannot figure this out.

```
public class MongoAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

  public MongoAppender () {
  }

  @Override
  public void start() {

    super.start();
  }

  public void append(ILoggingEvent event) {

    // Inserting log event into MongoDb
    // just got an error...
    // how do i send this error back to Swing Gui?
  }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but since you have `MongoAppender`  constructor name (now removed from the question): http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/04/mongodb-and-recording-appenders-for.html

Comment: removed MongoAppender to clean out the question. I have read your blogspot earlier but it was to advanced for me. will give it a go again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `append` i did not make and call to the gui.
I ended up writing to the DB whatever needed to be saved.

This of course is cleaner and safer then having classes trying to
address each other.